# Start task at once then by time interval using Rx framework

Tags: .net, system.reactive

I'm trying to run my task immediately, then to run it by time interval. 
I wrote the following :

```
var syncMailObservable = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15));
syncMailObservable.Subscribe(s => MyTask());
```

The problem is the task starts only after the 15 seconds. I need to run my task at the beginning then to continue by time interval.

How would I do that?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could do this:

```
var syncMailObservable =
    Observable
        .Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15.0), Scheduler.TaskPool)
        .StartWith(-1L);
syncMailObservable.Subscribe(s => MyTask());
```

Comment: Specify Scheduler.TaskPool in the Interval and you've got my vote :)

Comment: @PaulBetts - I've added the `Scheduler.TaskPool` to `Interval`, but why is `Scheduler.TaskPool` better than the default `Scheduler.ThreadPool`?

Comment: The actual scheduler isn't important, but it's usually a good idea to always specify an explicit scheduler so that it's clear that this code will run in another context. If you're using unit testing, you usually want to use your own global variable (like ReactiveUI's RxApp.TaskpoolScheduler) so that later in a unit test, you can replace it with a TestScheduler

Comment: @PaulBetts - Fair enough. I tend to write most of my extension methods and libraries with an explicit `IScheduler` for that reason. Cheers.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
Observable.Return(0).Concat(Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15)))
.Subscribe(_ => MyTask());
```

Answer (score 2):

This question refers to the Interval method specifically, but the Timer method can be used to accomplish this cleanly.

The Timer method supports an initial delay (due time). Setting it as a time span of zero should start the task at once, and then run it at each interval.

```
 var initialDelay = new TimeSpan(0);
 var interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15);

 Observable.Timer(initialDelay, interval, Scheduler.TaskPool)
     .Subscribe(_ => MyTask());
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh229652(v=vs.103).aspx